# Como forçar acesso HTTP (Não seguro)

Tags: htaccess, http, ssl

Ao acessar https://dominio.com ou https://www.dominio.com, o erro de segurança abaixo é exibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não possuo certificado SSL e não tenho necessidade nesse momento. Ao tentar forçar o redirecionamento para HTTP, não obtenho o resultado esperado.

De inúmeras formas tentei forçar o redirecionamento via .htaccess e atualmente está da seguinte forma:

```
# Elgg htaccess directives

<Files "htaccess_dist">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

# Don't allow listing directories
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Default handler
DirectoryIndex index.php


############################
# BROWSER CACHING

# The expires module controls the Expires and Cache-Control headers. Elgg sets
# these for dynamically generated files so this is just for static files.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Conditional requests are controlled through Last-Modified and ETag headers.
# Elgg sets these on dynamically generated cacheable files so this is just for
# static files. Note: Apache sends Last-Modified by default on static files so
# I don't think we need to be sending ETag for these files.
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|mp3|flv|mov|avi|3pg|html|htm|swf|js|css|ico)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>


############################
# PHP SETTINGS
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    # limit the maximum memory consumed by the php script to 64 MB
    php_value memory_limit 64M
    # register_globals is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 - disable it for security reasons.
    php_value register_globals 0
    # post_max_size is the maximum size of ALL the data that is POST'ed to php at a time (8 MB)
    php_value post_max_size 8388608
    # upload_max_filesize is the maximum size of a single uploaded file (50 MB)
    php_value upload_max_filesize 52428800
    # on development servers, set to 1 to display errors. Set to 0 on production servers.
    php_value display_errors 0
</IfModule>


############################
# COMPRESSION

# Turn on mod_gzip if available
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk yes
    mod_gzip_keep_workfiles No
    mod_gzip_minimum_file_size 1000
    mod_gzip_maximum_file_size 1000000
    mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size 1000000
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
    # Exclude old browsers and images since IE has trouble with this
    mod_gzip_item_exclude reqheader "User-Agent: .*Mozilla/4\..*\["
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
</IfModule>

## Apache2 deflate support if available
##
## Important note: mod_headers is required for correct functioning across proxies.
##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.[0678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

    # The following is to disable compression for actions. The reason being is that these
    # may offer direct downloads which (since the initial request comes in as text/html and headers
    # get changed in the script) get double compressed and become unusable when downloaded by IE.
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI action\/* no-gzip dont-vary
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI actions\/* no-gzip dont-vary

</IfModule>


############################
# REWRITE RULES

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

# If Elgg is in a subdirectory on your site, you might need to add a RewriteBase line
# containing the path from your site root to elgg's root. e.g. If your site is
# http://example.com/ and Elgg is in http://example.com/sites/elgg/, you might need
#
#RewriteBase /sites/elgg/
#
# here, only without the # in front.
#
# If you're not running Elgg in a subdirectory on your site, but still getting lots
# of 404 errors beyond the front page, you could instead try:
#
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]


# In for backwards compatibility
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^pg\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&page=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^tag\/(.+)\/?$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=search&page=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^action\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-\/]+)$ engine/handlers/action_handler.php?action=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^cache\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/cache_handler.php?request=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^services\/api\/([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/service_handler.php?handler=$1&request=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?view=$1&guid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^export\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9\_]+)\/$ engine/handlers/export_handler.php?view=$1&guid=$2&type=$3&idname=$4 [L]

RewriteRule xml-rpc.php engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php [L]
RewriteRule mt/mt-xmlrpc.cgi engine/handlers/xml-rpc_handler.php [L]


# rule for rewrite module test during install - can be removed after installation
RewriteRule ^rewrite.php$ install.php [L]

# Everything else that isn't a file gets routed through the page handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]+)\/(.*)$ engine/handlers/page_handler.php?handler=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]





</IfModule>
```

Comment: redirecione sem enviar o protocolo. exemplo: window.location.href='//dominio.com/arquivo.php'

Comment: o chrome causa esse incoveniente devido ao sistema de cache.. normalmente guarda o HSTS do servidor dns.. é necessário excluir o cookie referente ao domínio.. (limpar o cache do chrome). No servidor dns, para evitar que isso se repita, desative o HSTS. Há tb outros parâmetros que podem causar o mesmo problema, porém, esse é o mais comum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente alterar estas linhas no seu **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Para:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Value, @Ivan. Porém permanece o aviso e não forçou o redirecionamento HTTP.

Comment: experimente inverter a condição: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on, em último caso, vc desabilita o https:// pelo painel.

Comment: Segue alguns exemplos: https://wp-mix.com/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https/

Comment: Nem mesmo os exemplos conseguiram me salvar.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não vai ser possível porque ele não chega a acessar os arquivos do site para processar o redirecionamento. O navegador envia uma solicitação HTTPS ao servidor, não obtendo esse protocolo, ele emite o aviso de segurança. É normal acontecer isso.